# Sequence jump with CACHE option

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 db sequences and 2 tables:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE products_seq
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9999999999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE reviews_seq
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 9999999999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
                      id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY default nextval('products_seq'),
  //other fields
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews (
                         id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY default nextval('reviews_seq'),
//other fields
```

When I populate table via db script it populates correctly in db

```
INSERT INTO reviews (title, rating, description, product_id) VALUES
                 ('Great Product', 4.5, 'I love this product!', 1),
                 ('Disappointing', 2.0, 'Not what I expected.', 2),
//other records, 13 in common
```

But when I run `SELECT nextval('reviews_seq');` I see that next val for id is 21. I understand that this command increment sequence value every time, but why it starts from 21? This happens only for sequence with cache (in this case cache is 10). Works ok with no cache (next id=14 with `SELECT nextval('reviews_seq');`).

Comment: Read the docs [Create Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) in particular: *Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.*. Which means *Works ok with no cache*  will not be ok if an INSERT fails.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the sequence for each insert, `N` next values are put in a cache that remains in memory for the duration of the **session**. The sequence counter is increased by this same `N` value, so 1 or 10 in your example.

Since you have inserted 13 rows in a single session, the sequence has been increased by 10+10, so the next session calling it will get 21.

See the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) notes about concurrent sessions and "last value"